# Cannot use L,R,C to align the box center, right or left on the pdf page

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to write a PHP script to upload the data from the database to pdf page (FPDF) and I am trying to center the box which contains the data from the database on the pdf page but always I get an error saying "Use of undefined constant L - assumed 'L' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) " Is there a solution for this, I guess I am doing some mistake while writing the code please help me with my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is a simple error, but you've got to show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

If PHP gives the error 'Use of undefined constant X, assumed 'X', you are using the value as a constant, you need to enclose the value with quotes to use it as a string.

This is probably your current code:

```php
$this->Cell(0,10,'Left text',0,0,L);
```

this is what it should be:

```php
$this->Cell(0,10,'Left text',0,0,'L');
```

The alignment feature within the cell function is for text-alignment within the cell, not the cell alignment itself. http://fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm

As far as I know there is no method to align an object within the page. You should manually calculate the X position and set it before calling the method you are using. There are multiple ways to do this, but you could get the pageWidth, get the element width, substract the element width from the page width and devide by 2. That should be your X starting position for the element that needs to be centered.